# I work with vuejs mustache syntax don't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I work with vuejs  mustache syntax don't work
I work with vuejs  mustache syntax don't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>   
        <title>index</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
        <script>
           
            const app = new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data: {
                  message: "hello",
              },
            })
          </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="#app">
            <h5>{{message}}</h5>
        </div>
       
    </body>

</html>
```

[capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GttzB.png)

Comment: I think you have a typo. `id="#app"` probably should be `id="app"`

Comment: it should be `<div id="app">` not `<div id="#app">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `<div id="app">` not `<div id="#app">` and the script that includes the vue instance should be at the end of body element :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>   
        <title>index</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14"></script>
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <h5>{{message}}</h5>
        </div>
        <script>
           
            const app = new Vue({
              el: '#app',
              data: {
                  message: "hello",
              },
            })
          </script>
    </body>

</html>
```